# Why does my Swing worker thread interrupt work?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, backgroundworker, interrupt

I have a small java program, written in Eclipse using WindowBuilder, which works on reading data from UTF-8 text files and writing them into a database. To maintain the GUI's responsiveness, I use a swing worker thread, executed when clicking on a button.

```
btnex.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    public Void doInBackground() {
        String[] content = Reader.getContent(file);
        //do something with the content, if something goes wrong, set error to true.
    return null;
}
public void done() {
    if (!error) {
        //handle error
    }
};
worker.execute();
```

The function getContent in the class Reader extracts data from the file into the string array.

```
public static String[] getContent (String dbfile) {
    try {
        String[] lines = null;
        String[] linesplit = null;
        String store = "";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(dbfile), "UTF8"));
        String line = "";
        line = reader.readLine();
        linesplit = line.split(";");
        while (linesplit.length > 1 && !line.equals(null)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < linesplit.size(); i++) {
            store += StringFormer.decrypt(linesplit[i]) + " ";
            } //StringFormer is another class written by me, just for decrypting the string
            store += "\n";
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line.equals(null)) break;
            linesplit = line.split(";");
        }
        reader.close();
        lines = store.split("\n");
        return lines;
    } catch (Exception ex) { //...
    }
}
```

When I try to run my program and click the button, the program does not work correctly. So I run the program in debug mode, and as a result, the thead does not finish but somehow exits before finishing all work. This happens in getContent, after leaving the while loop but before working on reader.close(). Before leaving the while loop, the call stack in the debug view contains the calls of the button click and of getContent, next to others, but once I leave the loop, the two mentioned above are dropped and the next top stack member names the base swing worker class: SwingWorker$2(FutureTask).run.

Does anyone know, why the program does not finish the written work flow? I work with multiple threads in the program, but never two background threads are running at the same time.

Comment: Do you call `worker.get()` anywhere? You may need to call this in order to retrieve any exceptions thrown by the SwingWorker.

Comment: (1) "the program does not work correctly"--what exactly happens? Exception? Missing results? (2) I don't think it's a *requirement* to call `SwingWorker.publish`, which internally calls your `SwingWorker.process` method, and merely using them isn't likely to solve your problem, but it might help narrow down where the error is.

Comment: @DSlomer64: not sure if the point (3) was to me, but the `get()` method should be called when the SwingWorker is done, myself, I usually do this within a PropertyChangeListener, listening for newValue == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE. Doing this prevents calling get from blocking the EDT, and puts the responsibility of calling get and getting the exceptions on the calling code (as opposed to calling it from within the `done()` method).

Comment: I removed point (3). It was there because I've used `SwingWorker` a couple of times and thought I didn't use `get`. When I discovered I DID, I removed (3). Most recently I've done `doInBackground` with an Android app and it's NOT used there. Got confused. Other reason it was there was just as warning about blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:
The line if(line.equals(null) throws a NullPointerException. line is null when nothing more can be read out of the file, but the function equals requires that the compared variable is defined. Since line was null, equals threw the exception without me noticing it. The line has to be if(line==null).